# Primes $p$ for which $2p-1$ is prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

It's a well-known open problem (Sophie-Germain primes) whether there are infinitely many primes $p$, $2p+1$. What about $p$, $2p-1$?

Seemingly it's also an open problem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472622/pair-of-primes-of-the-form-4k3-and-8k5) and the linked question). 
I am aware that it is a special case of more general open problems.

But I'd like a concrete reference asserting that this specific problem is indeed open.

Edit: As I said, I'm not interested in more general conjectures. It's suitable for MO, because no one has given me a reference for this exact problem.

Comment: It's a special case of the Bateman-Horn conjecture. http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1962-16-079/S0025-5718-1962-0148632-7/home.html

Comment: Or Schinzel's hypothesis H. I think the problem is not lack of references but too many. Not really suitable for MO.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Also a simple consequence of Dickson's conjecture.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch But just because a more general conjecture is open doesn't mean a less general is as well.

Comment: Please read before downvoting and upvoting the other comment.

Comment: I think that the paper linked to by Carlo Beenakker pretty directly answers your question. It states "In this paper we focus our attention on Cunningham chains of length 2
of the second kind. As of January 2013 the largest known prime combination
has 44 652 decimal digits." These are exactly the types of numbers you are looking for and the formulation is chose to convey it is not known there are infinitely many

Comment: @quid, I did not get that impression from reading, but maybe that's just me. Anyway, I don't understand what about this question people such as FelipeVoloch or GHfromMO find "unsuitable".

Comment: @usul I think their point is that "everybody knows" this is open and very hard. I essentially share this view. Yet, if somebody seeks a neat quote-able reference for this fact possibly it is alright as reference-request. (But also note that this was not quite clear in the original version.)

Comment: @quid I originally said "I'd like a reference", and with the reference-request tag. In any case, citing more general open problems and arguing that it implies the special case problem is open is not complete evidence (though it could give a good idea).

Comment: The original version  said "Seemingly it's also an open problem [...]. But I'd like a reference." Then it's not completely clear to me what type of reference you are looking for. Your comments clarified that you are looking for a reference for *the fact that it is an open problem.* But you could have just as well been interested in a discussion of methods or progress towards this problem. In the latter case the more general references would be helpful. Indeed, requests of the form: "I want more information on the problem." are in my experience more common than "I want it asserted it is open."

Comment: @user236182: What I tried to point out is this: if you can solve one $k=2$ case of Dickson't conjecture, then you can probably solve all $k=2$ cases such as the twin prime conjecture or the case of Sophie Germain primes. This is clear to any expert who worked on these kinds of problems. Mathematics is not a formal game, conjectures and opinions are not born in a vacuum. It is a fact that your question is open: I and other users of this site are the reference if you wish. I could go ahead and publish a paper stating this, would it be better?

Comment: @user236182: One more thought. There are infinitely many open problems and only finitely many papers. So there are clearly many open problems for which there is no paper stating it is an open problem. And in fact it is the other way: a problem is open as long as there is no paper settling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Felipe Voloch that this question is not quite suitable for MO. At any rate, it is well-known (folklore) among number theorists that solving any single $k=2$ case of [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson's_conjecture) would be a major breakthrough. The best approximations we know are in the works of Green-Tao, Zhang-Maynard-Tao-Polymath (and studying these works makes one understand why any single $k=2$ case is hard).

Answer (score 4):

This is the "Cunningham chain of the second kind of length 2", here is the [OEIS reference](http://oeis.org/A005382) and here is the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain); record primes of this type are listed [here](https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=20), the currently largest known (52138 digits) prime $p$ such that $2p-1$ is also prime is $p=129431439657 \cdot 2^{170171} + 1$. It is a (still open) conjecture that the number of primes of this type less than $N$ grows with bound as $1.32\, N/\log^2 N$, see [*Sieving for large twin primes and Cunningham chains of length 2 of the second kind*](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_038_2012/117_38.pdf) (2012).